# Supporting square Facebook video embeds on mobile

Tags: facebook, video, mobile, embed

I use Facebook video embeds on my site, for videos that have both 1:1 and 16:9 dimensions. The dimensions are correct on desktop but on mobile devices the 1:1 square dimension videos are always inside of a 16:9 iframe with black bars on the side. I'd like it to print as square on mobile devices, like the videos do on the Facebook mobile app.

Is there a way to have a 1:1 square video on mobile web?

This is the code I'm working with.

```
<div class="video__wrapper js-video__wrapper fb-video"
data-allowfullscreen="1"
data-width="640"
data-height="640"
data-href="{url}"
style="height: 640px; min-height: 640px; width: 640px;">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
    <blockquote cite="{url}">
        <a href="{url}"></a>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @tristansokol – I have this same problem did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I also faced that issue and I've found that it's confirmed as a bug, but still there is no any solution for that issue. Visit the below link.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/657304034475449/